# Marking a file as viewed by a user

Tags: google-drive-api

I created a file using the create API

```
f_id = files().create(body={'name': 'Dummy', 'mimeType': '*/*'}, media_body='/abc.txt', fields='id')
```

Then I share this with everyone in my domain, by link(so marking allowFileDiscovery as False)

```
permissions().create(fileId=f_id, body={'type': 'domain', 'domain': ,'allowFileDiscovery': false, 'role': 'reader'}, fields='id').execute()
```

After this with a different user's service account, I do this to mark the file as viewed by the user

```
files().update(fileId=f_id, body={'viewedByMeTime': (datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=5)).isoformat("T") + "Z"}).execute()
```

This used to work until yesterday, but now I get this error

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<f_id>?alt=json returned "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.">

This still works for a folder I created with the same permissions, but not restricted to domain. I am using GDrive API version v3. Has there been any recent changes here which could cause this issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I can update the `viewedByMeTime` with an account from the domain, after creating the specified Permission. I think the issue might be related to your mention of `with a different user's service account`. What do you mean by `a different user's service account`? Service accounts don't belong to a specific user, but to an application. They also don't belong to your domain, so this account won't be included in the domain permission.

Comment: So, are you using a service account by itself, or you're just using it to impersonate another account in the domain after [granting domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)? If you're using it by itself, that might be what's causing this error.

Comment: I have domain wide delegation enabled `credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(self.key_file,
                                                                            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
                                                                            subject='u2@abc.com')
        return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)`

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this anymore. Not sure if this was some one off issue. Thanks for the pointers https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011/iamblichus